# HSDPA modem only working on certain USB ports

Tags: 10.04, configuration, usb-modem, huawei

Depending on which **USB port** I use to connect my **HSDPA modem**, the network manager will connect to the internet or not. I used to work (i.e. established a internet connection automatically) on all ports, but over time it simply stopped on some ports.

`lsusb` output in all cases looks like that (Device ID varies depending on USB port):

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E270 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
```

**Any ideas what could cause this behaviour? What can I do to fix this?**

**ADDED**
One additional information about the modem: if connected via USB it will be available as as harddrive **AND** as a HSDPA modem (kind of a duality...). In the error case, it will only be shown as a harddrive.

**ADDITIONAL INFO AS REQUESTED**

**MODEM NOT WORKING**

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:8000 Dell Computer Corp. BC02 Bluetooth Adapter   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E270 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem   
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c00c Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse   
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB   
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:0058 Dell Computer Corp. Port Replicator   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   

laptop:~$ dmesg | grep 'usb'   
[    0.225371] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs   
[    0.225387] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub   
[    0.225418] usbcore: registered new device driver usb   
[    0.504291] usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    0.504767] usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    0.505046] usb usb3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    0.505601] usb usb4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    1.061064] usb 1-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3   
[    1.192636] usb 1-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    1.447006] usb 2-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2   
[    1.634908] usb 2-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    1.708164] usb 1-6.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4   
[    1.801668] usb 1-6.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    2.076279] usb 1-6.1.1: new low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5   
[    2.174932] usb 1-6.1.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    6.580315] usb 1-6.1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address6   
[    6.683479] usb 1-6.1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[   20.018671] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb   
[   20.131703] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage   
[   20.131988] usb-storage: device found at 6   
[   20.131991] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning   
[   20.207981] usb 1-6.1.2: USB disconnect, address 6   
[   20.291499] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev   
[   20.297052] input: Logitech USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1.1/1-6.1.1:1.0/input/input6   
[   20.297465] generic-usb 0003:046D:C00C.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-6.1.1/input0   
[   20.297534] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid   
[   20.297803] usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver   
[   26.552360] usb 1-6.1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7   
[   26.663506] usb 1-6.1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[   26.709628] usb-storage: device found at 7   
[   26.709631] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning   
[   26.732387] usb-storage: device found at 7   
[   26.732390] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning   
[   31.709568] usb-storage: device scan complete   
[   31.733676] usb-storage: device scan complete
```

**MODEM WORKING**

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c00c Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:8000 Dell Computer Corp. BC02 Bluetooth Adapter   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E270 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   

dmesg | grep 'usb'   
[    0.134811] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs   
[    0.134826] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub   
[    0.134858] usbcore: registered new device driver usb   
[    0.360327] usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    0.360783] usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    0.361061] usb usb3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    0.361611] usb usb4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    1.144122] usb 2-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2   
[    1.346896] usb 2-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    1.588072] usb 3-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2   
[    1.761204] usb 3-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[    5.972042] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4   
[    6.115438] usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice   
[   19.990565] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial   
[   19.991429] usb-storage: device found at 4   
[   19.991432] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning   
[   20.017260] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage   
[   20.017305] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic   
[   20.017308] usbserial: USB Serial Driver core   
[   20.017817] usb-storage: device found at 4   
[   20.017820] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning   
[   20.070796] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb   
[   20.229525] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0   
[   20.229776] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1   
[   20.229843] usbcore: registered new interface driver option   
[   20.230396] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev   
[   20.246280] input: Logitech USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input6   
[   20.246438] generic-usb 0003:046D:C00C.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0   
[   20.246479] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid   
[   20.246483] usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver   
[   25.436579] usb-storage: device scan complete   
[   25.437674] usb-storage: device scan complete
```

Comment: Does all your USB ports work with other devices?

Comment: @N.N.: I have only seen problems with the modem. My USB ports seem to work just fine with e.g. memory sticks.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a complete dump of `lsusb` while the modem is attached to one of the ports that does not work.

Comment: @aquaherd: I'll provide a complete dump as soon as I am back in office.

Comment: If the number of ports in which it works reduced over time, it might be something wearing out, a physical problem. USBs tend to work or not, and not change unless something makes them.

Comment: @LewisGoddard: I don't think it is something physical: it stopped working on *all* ports of my external USB hub. After I connected the hub to another USB port of my laptop, the modem started working again if connected to the hub.

Comment: It might be interesting to see the output of dmesg in each case too.

Comment: @ed.: I'll provide the `dmesg` output as soon as I'm back in office. Left the laptop at work for the weekend... :-(

Comment: @ed.complete dumps and dmesg output added

Comment: @aquaherd:complete dumps and dmesg output added

Comment: You could force the device to always be at the same logical address.

Answer (score 2):

Given the output we can assume here the following:

- This has nothing to do with hardware failures.
- The modem has a virtual CD-ROM with Windows drivers, which are useless and only irritating here.
- The ubuntu modemmanager package is specifically crafted to handle these issues (e.g. suppress mounting of the fake CD-ROM) and has a growing database of modems and service providers. See [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G) if they already have yours and how to add it if they don't.
- There should be no need for hand-crafted texts like `wvdial.conf` or `99-udev-huawei-rules.conf` as outlined [here](http://oozie.fm.interia.pl/pro/huawei-e220/), it should work out of the box.
- It is most likely a bug, a missing entry or both. It even might have been fixed already, so you may have some success by trying a modemmanager / networkmanager PPA or test if it works in oneiric with a live CD.
- You might even have instant success if you ask your provider for an older variant of their modem (if it came bundled with your contract, the plan is available for longer than six months and the salesperson at the shop is smart enough to keep returned modems in a drawer, you name it.)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 for my E156G (black "3" Three italy 3G Internet provider) I noted that its works only attachet to an USB HUB, may be a communication issue that the HUB filters. A similar solution happenet for scanner driver over WMWare Windows XP virtualization port.

Two drivers are identifyed with the USB HUB and the original dialer works fine over Windows 7, but only one if I plug it directly on USB notebook port and the device are not fully recognized neither the dialer identify the hardware. The second driver does not appear. So, try to use an USB HUB between the device.

My USB HUB is a targus translucid blue one (Targus’ Ultra Mini USB 2.0 4-Port Hub).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make sure that when you connect, it is in the right mode. That is to say it should be recognized as the modem and not a compact disk.
There are a couple of ways in which you can achieve this,
one is to determine the id of the compact disk that it looks like, typically it is sr* where * can be some number.
You need to eject it using

```
sudo eject /dev/sr1
```

replace 1 with your relevant identifier looking at your dmesg.

You can use usb-modeswitch to automatically do it for you. It is available in the ubuntu repo if I'm not mistaken.
[Link here](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/)

Edit:

```
[Dialer cdma]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Baud = 115200
SetVolume = 0
;       New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Dial Command = ATDT
 Phone = #777
 Password = mts
 Username = internet@internet.mtsindia.in
/etc/wvdial.conf (END)
```

Here's my wvdial.conf, you'll need to make changes to the username and password depending upon the carrier you use and your location.

And yes when the modem works it is detected both as a storage device as well as the modem.

Comment: In case the modem is working, it is recognized as _both_ modem and harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

Your modem should work on any usb but hard drives do not on notebooks usually, because not all usb are equal (some do not supply power - or not sufficient for hard disks maybe). On my notebook I have 2 usb and 1 usb+firewire and hard drives that can't be powered on external power source work only on the usb+firewire one. Hard drive that have a PSU work in all usb.